# How do you enable scripts on a WordPress installation in Softaculous?

Tags: database, migration, scripts, backup

I am trying to migrate my website from one host to another, and I am not looking for a canned solution. Upon attempting to observe database information in the installation I discovered that the scripts were disabled on the installation that I am trying to migrate. So, I cannot figure out which database is associated with this installation to back it up before the migration. This is a live website, and I am attempting to not break it. How can I re-enable scripts on the installation? What plugins could be responsible for this? I have seen none that are responsible, but I can list those too if necessary. Is there a simple solution? Do I need to update the version, and if so how could I go about discovering the database information first to ensure that I am not going to break the site doing so? 
[image: Software Installations Page in Softaculous]

Comment: do you have phpmyadmin access?

Comment: @sialfa Yes, I do. But, I am unfamiliar on how that helps me figure out which database is associated with the installation that I am seeking to migrate.

Comment: If you access to phpmyadmin, you will see al the databases that are associated to your hosting plan. From there you can check what are the assigned database and then import you db dump!

Comment: Thank you, this answer definitely helped me to manage the databases, but still left me wondering which one was the correct database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the `wp-config.php` you can identify which database is being used:

```
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'this_here');
```

Then, use phpMyAdmin or Adminer to export the data into an .sql and move it over to the new database for import.

Comment: Thank you this specifically answered my question as to which database I needed to backup.